# Latency Replication Cassandra NoSQL

Tags: cassandra, nosql, replication, latency

How could I latency measure replication in Cassandra, NoSQL, or quantify of replicas updates in some time?

Answer (score 1):

What level of precision your looking for? To a point its not possible in a distributed system given clock drift and the speed of light. Easiest would be coordinator write latency as a measure of the round trip plus a little. Could also do a ping mapping, but once again sub ms its pretty difficult. The writes are measured in microseconds so hopefully the network latency should be dominating it with exceptions of the impact of GCs and OS.

The `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=CrossNodeLatency` metric might be meaningful as a C* level measure of time it takes a message to go from one node to another (or between DCs) but it does not account for clock drift.

Comment: Hi, Chris Lohfink.

What level of precision your looking for? 
R = Operations per second or time in miliseconds. I wish of mean time.

Picking up your idea, then I believe adding the write latency time on the source server plus "org.apache.cassandra.metrics: type = Messaging, name = Metric CrossNodeLatency" plus the write latency time on the destination server should provide an approximate result.

What do you think?

Very thanks!

Comment: Remember write latency is in microseconds. a write taking a full millisecond is pretty unusual. Excluding GCs - latencies between the nodes _should_ dominate the request.